# Why does Windows 7 require a password hint during setup?

Tags: passwords, windows, operating-systems

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think Windows 7 is the only operating system out there that requires a hint for the first user created on the system (have not had a chance to check out Windows 8 Beta).  **Why does Microsoft insist on requiring a hint for what could be seen as the root user?**  Of course you could always put something bogus in the field, but why **require** a hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because these devices are for mass consumption. Security must fight with dealing with a spectrum of users and usability. It is possible that users will only ever set up the first user. Let's face it, a good hint can be useful if created properly.  However, bad passwords are more common than bad hints.

Comment: Should I undersand your answer that Windows 7 doesn't have in-built (in all Windows) non-removable Administrator user?

Comment: You can remove the root administrator account. It has the potential to break a lot of things though if apps aren't written correctly. It sounds like @Logicalscope was referring to consumer users, not business users.

Comment: This questions was asked with businesses in mind, but logicalscope makes a good point that business is not the only market Microsoft is in.